# RquireJS with Module in TypeScript

Tags: module, requirejs, typescript

I'm studing TypeScript and RequireJS.
I want to simple module require but module type information missing.

Is there smart solution in such situation?

```js
requirejs(['backbone'], (Backbone) => {
    // In this function.
    // Backbone is 'any'
});

requirejs(['backbone'], (BackboneRef: Backbone) => {
    // error : Type reference cannot refer to container
    // 型参照でコンテナー 'Backbone' を参照できません。
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you need to do the following:

1. Download backbone.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped, the backbone.d.ts provides typescript strongly-typed interface, if you use IDE like Visual Studio, you can have all the intellisense support to Backbone
2. (Optional) Config backbone in RequireJS
3. In your TypeScript class, you can reference Backbone like the following

`

```
/// <amd-dependency path="backbone" />;
/// <reference path="path/to//backbone.d.ts" />;

export class YourModel extends Backbone.Model {

}
```

The amd-dependency tells the compiler how to reference backbone, so it would generate the correct define statement in JavaScript.

The reference provides a way to Backbone's definition for typed check.

Hope this helps!  TypeScript eliminates the hell of writing long define or require js statement, which can be error-prone in situation where there are lots of dependencies.

Comment: Apparently, this has become deprecated now.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-amd-dependency-